# F#: Equivalent to OCaml Async

Tags: asynchronous, f#, ocaml

Does F# have an equivalent to OCaml's Async library? Specifically, the ability to easily make Deferred values and execute functions when they are filled?

In particular, I want to wait until a particular reference changes, and then do something. In OCaml, I'd do this by making an ivar and calling its read function; how can I do this in F#?

Comment: [Asynchronous Workflows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233250.aspx) is a big selling point of F#. I can't say you can do a direct translation but you will almost certainly find something equivalent.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about [System.Lazy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx) (see also [the `lazy` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233247.aspx)).

Comment: @ildjarn Hm. I'm not sure. That looks to me like "here's a thing, don't evaluate it until I'm ready"; I want "Start this thing, tell me when it's ready."

Comment: please clarify with a link or a code example so that we can either learn or help.

Comment: @linkhyrule5 : That would be `Task<T>`. See also `Async.AwaitTask`, `Async.StartAsTask`, and `Async.StartChildAsTask`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Short answer

Yes, my [Hopac](https://github.com/Hopac/Hopac) library is a close relative of both Jane Street's Async library and the [asynchronous workflows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233250.aspx) of F# among many others.  Hopac is based on [Concurrent ML](http://cml.cs.uchicago.edu/) (CML) and arguably (as in technical terms rather than as a matter of opinion) currently provides a more expressive programming model than either of those.

## Longer answer

Jane Street's Async's [Deferred](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/111.17.00/doc/async_kernel/#Deferred) is much like .Net's [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Both are essentially [comonadic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2013/04/03/tasks-monads-and-linq.aspx) abstractions with a monadic layer written on top.

In Hopac, the closest relative to a Deferred is actually a [Promise](http://hopac.github.io/Hopac/Hopac.html#def:type%20Hopac.Promise).  However, Hopac doesn't directly provide a monadic layer for Promises.  Of course, you could easily write one, but I would advise to sit on it for awhile.  Rather, Hopac provides the [Job](http://hopac.github.io/Hopac/Hopac.html#def:type%20Hopac.Job) monad for encoding light-weight threads.  This is analogous to [how F#'s asynchronous workflows are defined](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/147194/async-padl-revised-v2.pdf) and feels more natural and [easier to reason about](http://tomasp.net/blog/csharp-async-gotchas.aspx/) in my subjective opinion.

Jane Street's Async's [Ivar](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/111.17.00/doc/async_kernel/#Ivar) is a close relative of Hopac's [IVar](http://hopac.github.io/Hopac/Hopac.html#def:type%20Hopac.IVar).  Both descend from the same lineage.

What makes CML and Hopac more expressive than Jane Street's Async and F#'s asynchronous workflows is the availability of combinators for synchronous events (CML) or [alternatives](http://hopac.github.io/Hopac/Hopac.html#def:type%20Hopac.Alt) (Hopac).  Using those many kinds of concurrent protocols can be encapsulated as first-class, extensible (higher-order), selective operations.

CML's and Hopac's synchronous [channels](http://hopac.github.io/Hopac/Hopac.html#def:type%20Hopac.Ch) support *simple rendezvous*, which means that both ends of a communication agree when communication happens.  This, in turn, has some interesting applications such as the ability to implement [Multicast channels](http://hopac.github.io/Hopac/Hopac.Extra.html#def:type%20Hopac.Extra.MChan) that support garbage collectable publish-subscribe style communications without need to explicitly cancel subscription (contrast with [Rx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx) [IObservable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-[IObserver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783449%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

## Specific answer

Here is an F# interactive session that first defines an IVar and then starts a concurrent Job that reads the value of the IVar and prints a message.  Finally the IVar is written to with a value:

```
> let nameVar : IVar<string> = ivar () ;;
val nameVar : IVar<string>
> start (nameVar |>> fun who -> printfn "Hello, %s!" who) ;;
val it : unit = ()
> run (nameVar <-= "Vesa") ;;
val it : unit = ()
> Hello, Vesa!
```

To produce this output, F# interactive was started with the [Hopac.fsx](https://github.com/Hopac/Hopac/blob/master/Hopac.fsx) script.

Answer (score 0):

> Does F# have an equivalent to OCaml's Async library?

F# has `async` built-in and more such as `MailboxProcessor`.

> Specifically, the ability to easily make Deferred values and execute functions when they are filled?

.NET provides `Task` which does that.